# logcat -d is giving incomplete logs

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I am using `logcat -d` to flush logs to a file programmatically. Below is the piece of code I wrote in the `onCreate()` to do the same:

```
Log.d(TAG, "First");
Log.d(TAG, "Second");
Log.d(TAG, "Third");
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line);
    }
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(FILE_PATH));
    printWriter.println(log.toString());
    printWriter.close();

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(log.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

The logs are not flushed completely. Sometimes, it dumps `First`, `Second` and `Third`, while at other times, it shows only few of the three. The worst case is, there are times when it dumps none.
To check if there are any `File` write issues, I also used `TextView`. Even the textView follows the same behavior.

**Why `logcat -d` is behaving unexpectedly?**

Comment: On modern Android versions, logcat run from an app userid will obtain only logs for that app

Comment: Exactly, My requirement is to get logs for only that App. I am only concerned about the logs that is created by the app(Say First, Second and Third here).

Comment: Does it ever get the 2nd or 3rd without the 1st?  If not, perhaps you have a race condition.  If you did this in a background thread, you could insert a brief sleep before the log reading attempt.

Comment: Yes, there are times when it gets 2nd and 3rd without 1st.

Comment: Thanks Chris, introducing sleep before each logging solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your adb and try to see directly the ddms logcat.

Comment: How to see the `ddms logcat` in Android Studio?